# memSQL How do I add partitions to an existing sharded table/database?

Tags: cluster-computing, scaling, singlestore

Adding nodes (leaves or aggregators) to a memSQL cluster is straightforward: I edited memsql_cluster.json and reran memsql-cluster setup. The problem is adding partitions to an existing table. The point here is to scale up: need to add more rows, but have exhausted the available memory in the original cluster.

I tried, for example:

```
mysql> create partition DMP:32 on 'ec2-X-Y-Z.compute-1.amazonaws.com':3306;

ERROR 1773 (HY000): Partition ordinal 32 is out of bounds. It must be in [0, 32).

mysql>
```

Reading the memsql docs,  I could not find any ddl option to change the number of partitions. I would prefer not to drop and recreate these tables. Any ideas on how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: ALTER TABLE, as documented, let's me add/drop columns, indices, and keys. Unfortunately not partitions.

Comment: This is good info, but not on memSQL's latest manual (http://developers.memsql.com/docs/latest/search.html#stq=%22partitioning-expression%22&stp=1 ) Am I looking at the wrong place? BTW, Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 4):

You cannot add more rows to an in-memory database when memory is already exhausted. That said, you can scale out (i.e. add more leaf nodes).

You can add more leaf nodes to your MemSQL cluster, then run rebalance_partitions to distribute your existing partitions evenly across the larger cluster. This will allow each of your partitions to consume more space in your cluster, allowing you to scale out.

If you just wanted to add more partitions, you can use mysqldump to export your MemSQL schema and data, recreate the database with more partitions, then load the schema and data back into your database that now has more partitions.

Learn more about rebalance_partitions here:
http://docs.memsql.com/docs/latest/ref/REBALANCE_PARTITIONS.html

Answer (score 1):

In order to re-partition the data currently you have to (1)export the schema and (2)data from your database (partitions are set on the database level), (3)recreate the database, and (4)reload everything back in.

You can dump database schema and tables to local files using mysqldump. It's best to run mysqldump twice, once to dump the schema and once to dump the data.

1. This command will create a file in the local directory containing the schemas for all tables in the DB:

   ```
   mysqldump -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -B <db_name> --no-data > schema.sql
   ```
2. If you have a large database and not enough local disk to dump all data at once you can specify some table(s) per command. For each one use a different filename (eg data1.sql, data2.sql, etc) and put one or more table names in as arguments. I would dump any smaller tables with one statement together and then dump any giant tables separately. Use this command:

   ```
   mysqldump -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -B <db_name> --no-create-info --tables <table1> <table2> <table3> > data1.sql
   ```
3. Once all tables and the schema have been dumped you can recreate the DB with more partitions. We generally recommend #partitions = #leaves * #cores/leaf. Use this command:

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE <db_name> PARTITIONS = <#_total_partitions>;
   ```

Confirm # of partitions with `"SHOW PARTITIONS ON <db_name>;"`

4. Insert the schema and data to the new database with these commands from the shell prompt:

   ```
   mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 < schema.sql

   mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 < data1.sql
   ```

The schema will take a few minutes to load. Time for data to load will depend on the size of the dataset. After each table completes its rows will be committed and queries can run against it.

Comment: Warning. By default schema.sql will contains the 'USE <db_name>;' statement and 'Drop Table' statement, that means it will overwrite your original database before building the new one. in case something go wrong, e.g. duplicate entry during < data1.sql operation, you may be in  big trouble as your original db already gone. I suggest import it to another new db then drop the old one.....for my case I need to add --replace in mysqldump otherwise I will get error when importing data. And then I find my original database is gone during import scheml.sql operation....